# Can any rooted Android phone be upgraded to version 2.2?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, updates, root-access

Assuming a given Android phone is [root-able](http://unrevoked.com/), is there any possibility that it cannot be upgraded to Android version 2.2 (or CyanogenMod 6)?

If such an upgrade isn't possible on a certain rooted Android phones, what are the factors that determine that? (hardware specs, other?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the minimum specification for Android 2.2 (Froyo)](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/686/what-is-the-minimum-specification-for-android-2-2-froyo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are more differences between Android devices than between different PC Machines. So you need to know things like which CPU and hardware and version of it you got in the device.  Then look for an Android firmware that supports your phone.  You might be able to compile your own firmware from source for your device, also depending on your devices hardware and how well you can handled fails there.

After an upgrade, your device will end up in different shape with regard to what works and not after the upgrade.  It might even work flawlessly.  You might even get a "bricked" device if you fail the upgrade and are a bit unlucky.

So, it all depends on what hardware you have and how good support Linux and Android has to your device hardware.

That is why the phone manufacturers and your telephone operator test the upgrades in many ways before they push it out to the customers.

But if you know this and are technical skilled and know that you *might* make your phone usless, you can always try.

Comment: This is a remarkably educating answer. The other thread pointed at the comment is very informative as well, but your answer adds a deeper level of understanding. Thanks + 1 + accepting.

Comment: Thanks.  It just states that you are on your own when upgradeing a rooted phone. So you should know that.  But it could be fun and usefull if you can find someone who has done this and it works for them (and some other). But I guess that you are still on your own, but the risk is less than making your own firmware :)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your hardware and the images of roms which may be available. There are many ROMS for many Android handsets out. Cyanogen has allowed many devices see 2.3.3 even if their provide hasn't released an update.

Like Anders said, there are possibilities of bricking your device deeming it unusable.

I know this, because I've done it to my HTC Magic, and half-bricked my HTC Desire Z (It's fine now! :) )